# Cell value dependant on Active cell

Tags: vba

Not sure if this is possible but there's so many creatives here i thought Id ask, I have a customer list with emails and amounts they owe in a table.

What I want to do is to select a cell with customers name(active cell"A1") and have another cell, lets say K2 show that customer's email address. I would like the same cell K2 to always display email address of the customers who's name is selected.

Then I can create 1 button that reads that cell(k2) and uses that as the 'email to'. Otherwise i will have hundreds of email buttons, one for each customer. I've tried a few codes online but can't figure it out.

I want to make a little more complex later on by adding their details into 1 hyperlink(to prefill form), but hopefully if i can get the basics right above i may be able to do the rest.

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly what you described, but you can use the SelectionChange event to set K2's value based on the most recently selected cell in column A:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Columns.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column = 1 Then Range("K2").Value = Target.Offset(0, 1).Value
End Sub
```

This code assumes you have names in column A (Target.Column = 1) and email addresses in column B (Target.Offset(0,1)).

If you select a single cell in column A, K2 is set to the corresponding value from column B.

If you select multiple cells in column A, or select cells outside column A, the SelectionChange event handler does nothing, and K2 retains the last value.

Comment: :D You're an absolute genius and I love you. It's doing exactly what I'm after, I'll try to CONCATENATE this into a link then add picture to the link and email out. Hopefully I can figure it out step by step but this helped greatly. Thanks Joe.

Answer (score 0):

I put a bit more complex solution here. The advantage of it that you can select any cells in the row of your data and it is limited to a specific range, which could be improve your speed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngData As Range
    Set rngData = Range("A2:D20") 'This is the range that holds your data
    'If you not selected anything in this range, there is nothing to do, leave the sub
    If Intersect(Target, rngData) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'I think it is a good practice to turn off the possible other events, though you not need it now
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ' Define in which column is the data you would like to put in K2
    Dim iColumnOfEmailAddress As Long
    iColumnOfEmailAddress = 2
    Range("K2").Value2 = Cells(Target.Row, iColumnOfEmailAddress).Value2
    Application.EnableEvents = True 'turn the events back
End Sub
```